# OneLogin Portal iOS App Not Sending Domain Redirect URI

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, onelogin

I have set up a Custom Connection in OneLogin using OpenId Connect. In OneLogin for my App settings in the SSO tab the Application Type is set to Web and Authentication Method is set to POST.

When using the OneLogin on the web my connection works as designed. The server is receiving the users OneLogin Domain Redirect Uri as the header

> Referral: {Domain Redirect URI}

in the first GET request to start the SSO process.

When using OneLogins mobile application OneLogin Portal, the server does not receive the header Domain Redirect URI and then cannot request the information necessary for that users request. Does anyone know if there is a setting that needs to be changed to allow users to connect via the OneLogin Portal application? It does not make any sense to me why these two devices would handle the OIDC SSO flow differently.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into the details of your configuration. There is a difference in how a device does and OIDC flow and how a mobile device does OIDC flow and how a browser does an OIDC flow.
RFC [7595 section 6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7595#section-6)
RFC [8252 section 7](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-7)

If the redirects are all valid, then it might be a software issue.
Have you tried this device flow on an android device?